# Shapefile in Tibco Spotfire

Tags: shapefile, spotfire, tibco

I have a map in Spotfire and I'm trying to add a shapefile as a feature layer. This shapefile represents most important italian cities (provinces). 
I have inserted it as a data table to the dashboard and I have added it as a feature layer to the map chart (coloring it by city), but it is not displayed in the map, I can't see the layer. 
I have also tried to join this shapefile with the feature layer already present in Spotfire (Feature layer --> Europe --> Europe Cities, that I can't use as feature layer because it doesn't show the shapes of the cities, it simply marks the cities), but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me? I think I am missing something.

Thank you very much,

Valentina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the coordinate reference system. It is in conflict with the map layer but at least I can see the feature layer now.